# Just open keyboard English when focus on editText

Tags: java, android

I need open keyboard English when user touch editText in android.

user maybe multi-keyboard EN, FA, AR,IT

Comment: Describe your question in details follow this [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't think it is possible. But you may limit the characters that EditText accepts

Answer (score 0):

You can open keyboard chooser dialog when user Focused on EditText by

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below code.

**Call this function in onCreate**

```
public static void hideKeyboardFrom(Context context, View view) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
```

**Call this function on EditText onTouchListener**

```
public static void showKeyboard(Context context, View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(view, 0);
    }
```